# sending json data into grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm receiving bunch of json objects which I want to display inside some grid. I want to avoid manual coding in my js like `echo div or echo table tr td, ...`

```
    success: function (result) {
                    $.each(result, function (i, item) {                           
                      //this I want to avoid  
                       document.getElementById("myTable").innerHTML = item.Title;
                    });
                },
```

How can these be done?

Thanks

Comment: Try jQuery Datatables: http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/ajax.html

Comment: SlickGrid is also good: https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Jquery DataTables look ok, can you show me concrete implementation on my example?